# Having issues running py, python3, python etc. Environment Variables correct as far as I can tell

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

I have used Django in the past but just got this new computer and was running though the Django tutorial a refresher. Having issues running the python manage.py runserver command. I get "Python was not foun; run....." error. I've tried py, python, python3. I have made sure my path varibles are set correctly. Not really sure what to try next. The only thing that is different on this PC than other computers Ive used is my username has been set as (username.computername) not really sure but it has messed with some code I use to get the user for file directories. I added a path variable with my full path instead of the %USERPROFILE% incase this was effecting something.
[Path Varibles](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZHKkt.png)
[Image of CMD](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V0ahB.png)
I have also looked at the "Manage App Execution Aliases" and python is clicked to on.
Thanks in advance for any help

here is what I'm getting from CMD:

```
C:\Users\jlr.DESKTOP-4N4QMUN\Documents\GitHub\Tracker_Reporting>py --version Python 3.11.4

C:\Users\jlr.DESKTOP-4N4QMUN\Documents\GitHub\Tracker_Reporting>python --version Python was not found; run without arguments to install from the Microsoft Store, or disable this shortcut from Settings > Manage App Execution Aliases.

C:\Users\jlr.DESKTOP-4N4QMUN\Documents\GitHub\Tracker_Reporting>python3 --version Python was not found; run without arguments to install from the Microsoft Store, or disable this shortcut from Settings > Manage App Execution Aliases.

C:\Users\jlr.DESKTOP-4N4QMUN\Documents\GitHub\Tracker_Reporting>where py C:\Windows\py.exe

C:\Users\jlr.DESKTOP-4N4QMUN\Documents\GitHub\Tracker_Reporting>where python C:\Users\jlr.DESKTOP-4N4QMUN\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\python.exe C:\Users\jlr.DESKTOP-4N4QMUN\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\python.exe

C:\Users\jlr.DESKTOP-4N4QMUN\Documents\GitHub\Tracker_Reporting>where python3 C:\Users\jlr.DESKTOP-4N4QMUN\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\python3.exe

C:\Users\jlr.DESKTOP-4N4QMUN\Documents\GitHub\Tracker_Reporting>py manage.py runserver Python was not found; run without arguments to install from the Microsoft Store, or disable this shortcut from Settings > Manage App Execution Aliases.

C:\Users\jlr.DESKTOP-4N4QMUN\Documents\GitHub\Tracker_Reporting>python manage.py runserver Python was not found; run without arguments to install from the Microsoft Store, or disable this shortcut from Settings > Manage App Execution Aliases.

C:\Users\jlr.DESKTOP-4N4QMUN\Documents\GitHub\Tracker_Reporting>python3 manage.py runserver Python was not found; run without arguments to install from the Microsoft Store, or disable this shortcut from Settings > Manage App Execution Aliases.
```

Comment: if you run it as `C:\Users\jlr.DESKTOP-4N4QMUN\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\python.exe manage.py runserver` does it work? and what is the current PATH value?

Comment: You might know this but it would not hurt to remind you/others that updating your env (like path) will not have an impact on any currently opened shells/consoles/apps.

Answer (score 0):

I Turned off Python in the manage app execution. It is now working, still pretty new to this and not sure why that solved it but I am good to go!

Cheers.